# how to make makefiles in unix with vi editor

Tags: unix, makefile, vi

```
assignment1: treecomp.h treefunction.c assignment1.c
      gcc -Wall -ansi -o assignment1.c treecomp.h treefunction.c
```

I typed in just the two lines above in unix vi editor.

Is this correct to make makefiles?

When I type in make in the command line, it doesn't make one.

Can anyone tell me how to make makfile?

I've been watching one of the youtube videos that shows you how to make makefilles and followed that but doesn't work.

Comment: This argument `-o assignment1.c` tells gcc to write it's *output* to assignment1.c, which will clobber your source file.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can do anything with Make, you must know how to do it *without* Make.

To build `assignment1` from `treecomp.h`, `treefunction.c`, and `assignment1.c`, you would invoke gcc like this:

```
  gcc -Wall -ansi -o assignment1 assignment1.c treefunction.c
```

Study this until you understand it. You can try omitting parts and see what happens, that's a valid engineering technique.

Once you understand that, you can write a Make rule:

```
assignment1: treecomp.h treefunction.c assignment1.c
    gcc -Wall -ansi -o assignment1 assignment1.c treefunction.c
```

Note that the whitespace before the `gcc` is a TAB, not four spaces.

Put that rule into a makefile (called e.g. "Makefile") and you can invoke Make by typing

```
make
```

This makefile is *crude but effective*. Many refinements are possible once you have the basic elements working.